# What GitHub permissions does CodePipeline need to work with a repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I noticed that AWS CodeBuild only needs read-only permissions to rely on a GitHub repository. AWS CodePipeline did not with no substantive error. Instead the repositories would just not show up.

What permissions does CodePipeline need to work with a GitHub repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can provide a Personal Authorization Token that only has Public Repo Read In a CloudFormation Template.

Setup in GitHub and copy the Personal Authorization Token
[image]
[image]

Then In your CloudFormation for CodePipeline

```
### Builds CI/CD pipeline Stages and Actions
Pipeline:
Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
Properties:
  ArtifactStore: 
    Type: S3
    Location: !Join ["-", ["byu", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", !Ref "AWS::Region", "code-build-artifacts" ]]
  #RoleArn: !Ref CodePipelineServiceRole
  RoleArn: !Join ["",["arn:aws:iam::", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":role/CodePipelineServiceRole"]]
  Stages:
  ### Defines Source repository via params
  - Name: !Join ["-",["Source", !Ref GitHubBranch, !Ref GitHubRepository]]
    Actions:
    - InputArtifacts: []
      Name: Source
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Source
        Owner: ThirdParty
        Version: '1'
        Provider: GitHub
      OutputArtifacts:
      - Name: MyApp
      Configuration:
        Owner: !Ref GitHubUser
        Repo: !Ref GitHubRepository
        Branch: !Ref GitHubBranch
        OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubToken
      RunOrder: 1
```

We are using !Ref to access CloudFormation Parameters that can be passed in via the cli - this keeps us from  having access keys in code :O

```
Parameters:
  GitHubUser:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub user name or organization name - whichever prepends the repo name
  GitHubRepository:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub repository name (not url)
  GitHubBranch:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub repository branch
  GitHubToken:
    Type: String
    Description: GitHub personal-access-token - see
```

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

The GitHub username is either the username or organization name - whichever show up before your repo name.

[Full example](https://github.com/byu-oit-appdev/iac/tree/master/cloudformation/codepipeline)

Comment: I would recommend adding a NoEcho: true to the GitHubToken parameter to prevent it from being visible when describing the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the GitHub account being used with AWS CodePipeline needs full admin access in order for CodePipeline to be able to use it.

Comment: ```Make sure the token is configured to have the following GitHub scopes: admin:repo_hook and repo``` from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-gs2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a GitHub repository as the source, you must create:

- A GitHub Access Token, with scopes `repo` and `admin:repo_hook`.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#github

[image]